# Android Image Comparison

Tags: java, android, image, comparison, cielab

I'm working on an Android application which should make the operation of comparing two images.Before comparison I should make the image conversion from RGB to CIELAB and then compare the obtained value from each image.If the value is the same -> the images are the same,if not images are not the same.
Can you help me with some tips ?(how to make conversion of an Bitmap image to CIELAB or anything like that)

Comment: @GeorgianAlin Please don't edit other peoples' posts. If you want to make a question of your own, make a question of your own. On the other hand, it appears that you are the same user that asked this question, but with a different account; you just lost access. In that case, please try to recover your login info. I believe you can email team@stackexchange.com for help.

Comment: @Quincunx I know the OP, he is a colleague of mine. It is indeed the same person that posted the question and edited it. By mistake he created two separate accounts, but he is now trying to merge them using the instructions found here http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts